# Oracle Schema Design: Seperate Schema with I/O Overhead?

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle11g, schema-design

We are designing database schema for a new system based on Oracle 11gR1. We have identified a main schema which would have close to 100 tables, these will be accessed from the front end Java application.

We have a requirement to audit the values which got changed in close to 50 tables, this has to be done every row.

Which means, it is possible that, for a single row in `MYSYS.T1` there might be 50 (or more or even less, but minimum 1) rows in `MYSYS_AUDIT.T1_AUD` table. We might be having old values of every column entry and new values available from `T1`.

DBA gave an observation, advising against this method, because he said, *separate schema meant an extra I/O for every operation*. Basically AUDIT schema would be used only to do some analyse and enter values (thus `SELECT` and `INSERT`).

Is it true that, "a separate schema means an extra I/O" ? I could not find justification.

It appears logical to me, as the AUDIT data should not be tampered with, so a separate schema.

Also, we designed a separate schema for archiving some tables from `MYSYS`. From `MYSYS_ARC` the table might be backed up into tapes or deleted after sufficient time.

**Few stats:** 
Few tables (close to 20, 30) in `MYSYS` schema could grow to around 50M rows. 
We have asked for a total disk space of 4 TB. 
`MYSYS_AUDIT` schema might be having 10 times that of `MYSYS` but we wont keep them more than 3 months. 
Handful of tables in MYSYS will have the following transactions/mins.

- 100 `INSERT` in `MYSYS` meaning same number of inserts into `MYSYS_AUDIT` tables.
- 1000 `UPDATE` in `MYSYS` tables meaning same number of inserts in `MYSYS_ADIT` tables.

**Questions:** 
Given all these, can you suggest me any improvements?

1. Separate schema affects disc I/O? (one extra I/O for every schema ?)
2. Any general suggestions?

**Figure:**

```
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
|       MYSYS       |          |     MYSYS_AUDIT   |
|                   |          |                   |
|    1. T1          |          |     1. T1_AUD     |
|    2. T2          |          |     2. T2_AUD     |
|    3. T3          |--------->|     3. T3_AUD     |
|    4. T4          |(SELECT,  |     4. T4_AUD     |
|     .             | INSERT)  |      .            |
|     .             |          |      .            |
|     .             |          |      .            |
|  100. T100        |          |    50. T50_AUD    |
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |(INSERT)
        |
        |
        |
        *
+-------------------+
|   MYSYS_ARC       |
|                   |
|    1. T1_ARC      |
|    2. T2_ARC      |
|    3. T3_ARC      |
|    4. T4_ARC      |
|     .             |
|     .             |
|     .             |
|  100. T100_ARC    |
+-------------------+
```

Apart from this, we have two more schemas with only read only rights, but mainly they are for adhoc purpose and we dont mind the performance on them.

**Suggestions:** 
There are couple of suggestions. We are agreed to on the following.

1. Schema for logical separations.
2. `TRIGGER` for inserting data into AUDIT tables.
3. Table names will not have `_AUD` suffix. :)
4. Procedure to populate `ARCHIVE` schema tables.
5. Partitions based on intervals.

We are analyzing ...

1. Workspace manager option.

The question is still open for further suggestions before accepting APC's or dpbradely's solution.

Comment: "separate schema meant an extra I/O"... either you misheard or that DBA needs to find another career, to put it kindly.

Comment: Lolzz.. @Jeffrey, I am pretty sure he said that. Not going to trouble him much now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a separate schema is definitely the way to go.  Apart from anything else it means you can use the same table names - `MYSYS.T1` and `MYSYS_AUDIT.T1` - which is helpful if you have tables with long names (>25 chars).

But the main virtue of the separate schema is that the audit tables can be shielded from accidental or mischievous tampering.

The impact of inserting audit rows, e,g, from a trigger, remains regardless of who owns the tables.

**general table design advice**

It is a good idea to give the audit tables the same structure as the main table.  So if you have metadata columns which you need for auditing, such as revision number, include them on the main table.  Also, populate the audit tables with new values, not old.  That is, when a new record is inserted into `MYSYS.T1` insert a matching record into `MYSYS_AUDIT.T1`; when an existing record is updated into `MYSYS.T1` insert a new record into `MYSYS_AUDIT.T1`.  It is a lot easier to validate and report on the audit tables if their latest records are the same as the current ones in the main tables.

**use of triggers**

Auditing doesn't need to be complicated.  All we need is an insert statement in a `before insert or update or delete trigger`.   These are easily be generated from the data dictionary view USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

Comment: You bought in an info I forgot. We are going to use a `TRIGGER` for inserting into MYSYS_AUDIT tables. We considered doing this procedurally, but this is only one trigger. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Having the objects in a separate schema will not cause extra I/O - perhaps there was a misunderstanding and what your DBA meant to say was that the presence of auditing would result in extra I/O, which of course will be true no matter how you implement it.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Yup. There is always an extra I/O for auditing. Any other general suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at range partitioning for the audit data. You might want to ship auditing data to less expensive storage. Partitioning makes it easy to ship, for example a month of data, to another server. Or to delete autiting records older than a month.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Interval_partitioning

Comment: +1. Thanks for suggestion on range partitioning. We had that on our plans, forgot to mention here. I love **Dr. Strange love.**. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to APC's answer.

Could take a look at [Workspace Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28396/long_intro.htm#ADWSM010), could be better than triggers as they can fail or be disabled etc.

Comment: +1. Thanks for that suggestion on workspace manager. Need to do some analysis on that.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have the money, look at Oracle's [Total Recall](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Total_Recall)